Criterion for self-adjointness of non-negative symmetric operators
In a paper by Strichartz, the author claims the following:

A densely-defined, closed, symmetric, non-negative operator $A$ (i.e. $\langle Ax,y\rangle\geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathcal{D}(A)$) is self-adjoint iff there are no eigenvectors with with negative eigenvalues in the domain of $A^{\ast}$.

I try to understand why this is the claim. He cites Reed-Simon II (p.136-137), but I am not able to make a connection with this claim.

First of all, let us extract the relevant statements of Reed-Simons (Theorem X.1 and the Corollary on the next page):

Let $A$ be a densely-defined, closed and symmetric operator on some
Hilbert space. Then:

$\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{ker}(\lambda-A^{\ast}))$ is constant on the open upper half-plane $\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\mid
> \mathrm{Im}(\lambda)>0\}$ and on the open lower half-plane
$\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\mid \mathrm{Im}(\lambda)<0\}$. Let us denote
these two numbers $\mathcal{N}^{\pm}$ ( deficiency indices).
$A$ is self-adjoint if and only if $\mathcal{N}^{+}=\mathcal{N}^{-}=0$.
If $\langle Ax,x\rangle\geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathcal{D}(A)$, i.e. if $A$ is non-negative, then
$\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{ker}(\lambda-\sf{A}^{\ast}))$ is constant on
$\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\backslash [0,\infty)$.


Now, we can proof your claim:

Let $A$ be a densely-defined, closed, non-negative and symmetric operator on some Hilbert space. Then $A$ is self-adjoint if and only if the only solution $u\in\mathcal{D}(A^{\ast})$ of $A^{\ast}u=\lambda u$ for any $\lambda<0$ is the trivial one, i.e. $u=0$.

Proof.

"$\Rightarrow$'': If $A$ is self-adjoint and non-negative, then $\sigma(A)\subset [0,\infty)$. See for instance this post. This immidiately implies the claim.
"$\Leftarrow$'' By assumption, $\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{ker}(\lambda-A^{\ast}))=0$ for all $\lambda<0$. Since $A$ is non-negative, by 3. above, the number  $\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{ker}(\lambda-A^{\ast}))=0$ is constant on $\lambda\backslash [0,\infty)$ and hence, this implies $\mathcal{N}^{+}=\mathcal{N}^{-}=0$ (see also 1.). Hence, $A$ must be self-adjoint by 2.

